# Undefined reference to crcsum(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned short)

Tags: c, parameters, arduino, undefined-reference, crc16

I am trying to implement a CRC16 in an arduino sketch. I got the crc.c file from online and I wanted to try it out. I created the other files to allow crc.c to run correctly. Here are my files.

crc.h:

```
#ifndef CRC_C_
#define CRC_C_

unsigned short crcsum(const unsigned char* message, unsigned long length, unsigned short crc);
int crcverify(const unsigned char* message, unsigned long length);
void crcappend(unsigned char* message, unsigned long length);


#endif // CRC_C_
```

crc.c:

```
/*
 * Derived from CRC algorithm for JTAG ICE mkII, published in Atmel
 * Appnote AVR067.  Converted from C++ to C.
 */

#include "crc.h"

/* CRC16 Definitions */
static const unsigned short crc_table[256] = {
  0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
  0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
  0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
  0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
  0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
  0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
  0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
  0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
  0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
  0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
  0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
  0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
  0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
  0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
  0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
  0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
  0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
  0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
  0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
  0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
  0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
  0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
  0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
  0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
  0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
  0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
  0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
  0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
  0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
  0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
  0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
  0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78
 };

/* CRC calculation macros */
#define CRC_INIT 0xFFFF
#define CRC(crcval,newchar) crcval = (crcval >> 8) ^ \
    crc_table[(crcval ^ newchar) & 0x00ff]

unsigned short crcsum(const unsigned char* message, unsigned long length,
   unsigned short crc)
{
  unsigned long i;

  for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
  CRC(crc, message[i]);
}
   return crc;
}

int crcverify(const unsigned char* message, unsigned long length)
{
   /*
   * Returns true if the last two bytes in a message is the crc of the
   * preceding bytes.
   */
  unsigned short expected;

  expected = crcsum(message, length - 2, CRC_INIT);
   return (expected & 0xff) == message[length - 2] &&
    ((expected >> 8) & 0xff) == message[length - 1];
}

void crcappend(unsigned char* message, unsigned long length)
{
  unsigned long crc;

  crc = crcsum(message, length, CRC_INIT);
  message[length] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0xff);
  message[length+1] = (unsigned char)((crc >> 8) & 0xff);
}
```

I call the function "crcsum" in the following file.

crc.ino:

```
#include "crc.h"

void setup() {

crcsum((const unsigned char*)"0123456789", 50000, 4);  


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The problem is that I get the following error.

```
crc.cpp.o: In function `setup':
/Users/SuperDuperBro/crc.ino:10: undefined reference to `crcsum(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned short)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

I know that my header file and functions are operating correctly because when I comment out the function call in crc.ino, everything compiles just fine.

Why am I getting this error? I have looked online and have been trying to fix it for a while, but I haven't had any luck. My guess is that the problem has to be something with the function parameters. I tried adjusting the parameters, but to no avail. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: show your call to your compiler.

Comment: Show your compilation statement.

Comment: This is a linker error. You want to tell the linker (via telling the compiler) which object file contains the result of compiling the sources for `crcsum()`.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what does it look like when you call a compiler? I don't have a call to the compiler. Is this something that is unique to arduino?

Comment: I added the full error. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add crc.c into your arduino project?

Either wrap your include of crc.h with extern "C" or rename the crc.c into crc.ino:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "crc.h"
}

void setup() {
    crcsum((const unsigned char*)"0123456789", 50000, 4);  
}
```

The compiled function name would be different between C and C++. `crcsum(...)` name after C compiler would be just _crcsum. After c++ compiler the name would be something like `crcsum__Fcii`. extern "C" just tells compiler to expect these names to be in C format.

Comment: This fixed my compilation error! I'm just curious, but what exactly does extern "C" do? Thanks again!

Comment: The compiled function name would be different between C and C++. crcsum(...) name after C compiler would be just _crcsum. After c++ compiler the name would be something like crcsum__Fcii. extern "C" just tells compiler to expect these names to be in C format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing C and C++ code (Arduino code is typically C++).

To fix, either compile crc.c as C++ code by renaming the file to crc.cpp, or add an appropriate `extern "C"` to crc.h.

Comment: Oh no! Haha I can't believe I didn't notice the .cpp file extension. I will try and add extern "C" to the header file. Would I have to change all of my code to C++ if I renamed the files (I haven't worked at all with C++)?  I thought arduino sketches accepted C and C++

Answer (score -3):

Look very carefully at the function prototype as you declare it:

```
unsigned short crcsum(const unsigned char* message, unsigned long length,
   unsigned short crc)
```

Now look carefully at the place where you call it:

```
crcsum((const unsigned char*)"0123456789", 50000, 4);
```

Tell me, what type is `50000`? What type is `4`?

Try casting them to `unsigned long` and `unsigned short` respectively and see if the error doesn't go away.

Comment: What are some examples that I could use as parameters? I might have goofed